# PayPal IPN Won't Execute Certain Part(s) of Code

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to work with with the PayPal IPN system. I have setup my code to use their SandBox platform for testing. I am looking for a reason as to why the `if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {` parts of my code is NOT executing. Not only that, but none of the part of this code are writing any output to "log.txt".

I would appreciate a review of my code to let me know where I am going wrong.

```
<?php
require_once('includes/mysql.inc.php');

if($_POST) {
    $req = 'cmd=' . urlencode('_notify-validate');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        file_put_contents('log.txt', 'httperrrrr');
        die();
    } else {
        file_put_contents('log.txt', 'die here');
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            $data = print_r($res, TRUE);
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                file_put_contents('log.txt', 'verified');
                $username = $_POST['custom'];
                require_once('classes/admin.class.php');
                $activate = new Admin($db);
                $activate->modifyUser($username, 'activate');
            } else {
                file_put_contents('log.txt', 'noverifyshit');
            }
        }
    } else {
        file_put_contents('log.txt', 'no post');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe it cannot write to the file? Try adding error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors',1) just before this code you are executing (if you do not already have it anywhere else in your code).

Comment: Well, that actually helped me out a lot. Conditions are running now, just not the one I need to run.... "if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {"

Comment: Maybe he result from paypal includes some extra whitespace? The most obvious reason for the comparison failing is simply that the strings are not the same.

Comment: No. This is very weird. When I run a PayPal IPN test through the SandBox system, it works perfectly. When I switch from sandbox to just paypal.com, it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: If I try this fgets returns a shitload of headers as well. I imagine those are the ones causing trouble for you. Also, not sure whether it is just the pasted code here or not, but you have a double `else` statement in this code, which made my PHP bork up.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I simply added "if ($_POST['payment_status'] = "Completed") {" and the code executes to true now.

Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require_once('includes/mysql.inc.php');

if($_POST) {
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if (!$fp) {
        file_put_contents('log.txt', 'httperrrrr');
        die();
    } else {
        file_put_contents('log.txt', 'die here');
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                if ($_POST['payment_status'] = "Completed") {
                    file_put_contents('log.txt', 'verified');
                    $username = $_POST['custom'];
                    require_once('classes/admin.class.php');
                    $activate = new Admin($db);
                    $activate->modifyUser($username, 'activate');
                }
            } else {
                file_put_contents('log.txt', $_POST['payment_status']);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```